# Steam doesn't open - no errors

Tags: xubuntu, steam

For some reason my Steam just broke today after working perfectly since I installed it a few days ago.

It was originally installed via the deb from the Steam site. So I uninstalled that using the Ubuntu Software Center. Then I installed `steam-launcher`. When I run it from the menu it does nothing at all. When I go through terminal it gives this message, no error:

```
$ steam/usr/bin/steam: 
line 196: /home/andrew/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: Success
```

So I purge-removed it and removed the .steams directory from my home directory but on re-installation its the same story.

I am using Xubuntu 12.10 64bit.

It appears that steam `.local/share/Steam/steam.sh` is blank. What is it meant to have in it? I am so confused with how reinstalling it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

fixed this after deleting `.local/share/Steam` and `/usr/bin/steam*`

(EDIT: The content inside the 'local' folder might delete saves, games' settings and screenshots. So you might want to backup some files before deleting the folder - check for files inside `.local/share/Steam/steamapps`.)

Comment: Does this erase any local save / game data? Or is everything stored online via Steam?

Answer (score 5):

I also had an empty steam.sh. To solve it I did the following:

1. Delete `/home/user/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh`
2. Run `/usr/bin/steam`
3. Maybe you'll need to install some missing library (in my case I did, but can't remember which one - terminal window closed too soon. Sorry.)
4. Missing content (steam.sh) will be downloaded again.

Comment: missing library @SteamOS 2.0 - 4.11.12-1 was just this one - “libc.so.6”