# Steam will not start, and .steam file doesn't appear

Tags: steam

For me, when I type 'steam' into the terminal I get this:

```
/usr/bin/steam: line 194: /home/owner/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: Success
```

But still, steam refuses to start, and the .steam file doesn't appear to be on my computer either.

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04.

How can I debug/fix this?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I came across this in my searches. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/271404